# Problem with saving information on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to set this form page, the information is being sent but the database is not being created automatically, and consequently, my info is not being saved
Sorry for the long post and thanks for any feedback

**This is my app.js**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cloud', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

require('./models/post');
const post = mongoose.model('post');

const app = express();

app.post('/cloud', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render('index', {
                msg: err
            });
        } else {
            console.log(req.body);
            const newUser = {
                title: req.body.title,
            }
            new post(newUser).save().catch(post => {
                res.redirect('/cloud');
            })
        }
    });
});

app.get('/cloud', (req, res) => {
    post.find({})
    .sort({Date: 'desc'})
        .then(posts => {
            res.render('cloud/cloud', {
                posts: posts
            });
        });
});
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`running ${port}`);
});
```

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const postSchema = new Schema ({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
mongoose.model('post', postSchema);
```

**Handlebars file**

```
{{#each posts}}
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
{{else}}
<p>No pics found</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Please refer: https://www.kompulsa.com/introduction-mongoose-storing-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify your schema property at this line of your code.

```
new post(newUser).save().catch(post => {
                res.redirect('/cloud');

The correct way is 
new post({title: new User} ).save().catch(post => {
                res.redirect('/cloud');
```

Now, you have specify mongoose to save a new record for title.